# Method must always have a return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3. Here's a sample method:

```
  def all_users
    users.as_json
  end
```

Must we always have a `return` in a method? The above works, but is th

```
  def all_users
    u = users.as_json
    u
  end
```

Another thing, I tried to apply `returning`, but it must always be enclosed with `do ... end`?

Any better way to write methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubyists prefer omitting `return` keyword when they can. So in your case, this is the preferred way to write the method

```
def all_users
  users.as_json
end
```

And to your second question

```
I tried to apply returning, but it must always be enclosed with do ... end?
```

`do` and `end` are as a combination are used to write something called "blocks" in Ruby. Practically speaking, blocks are special kind of iterative methods that work on arrays, hashes, enumerable etc. You don't have to enclose `return` keyword within `do` and `end`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, the last *executed* (thanks mharper) line of a method is returned.

So this:

```
def all_users
  users.as_json
end
```

This:

```
def all_users
  u = users.as_json
  u
end
```

And this:

```
def all_users
  u = users.as_json
  return u
end
```

Do the same thing.

Comment: To be abundantly clear, the value of the last line *executed* in a method is return.  Consider the return value of an if-else statement as the body of the method.